# Как записать свойства в объект через переменную?

Tags: javascript

```
function abs(name, values) {
    obj = {}
    obj[name] = values
    return obj
}
abs('good', 100)
abs('bad', 10)
abs('normal', 50)
alert(obj.good)
alert(obj.bad)
alert(obj.normal)
```

Свойство заменяется каждый раз при вызове, а нужно, чтобы объект имел 3 разные свойства.

Comment: @zloctb, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(function(){
  var obj = {};
  window.abs = function(name, values) {
    obj[ name ] = values;
    return obj;
  }
}());

abs('good',100);
abs('bad',10);
abs('normal',50);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, как код работает поняли?

Comment: не очень!Создается глабальная переменная через которую получаем доступ к приватному свойтву( var obj)?

Comment: Его Величество Замыкание

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};
function abs(name, value) {
    obj[name] = value;
    return obj;
}
abs('good', 100);
abs('bad', 10);
abs('normal', 50);
alert(obj.good);
alert(obj.bad);
alert(obj.normal);
```